# Eclipse navigation bar above editor

Tags: eclipse, editor

Please see the attached image. My editor somehow got this navigation bar at the top which is very annoying and has slowed down loading of each file. Can someone tell me how to remove this?

Thanks in advance!

--Sudoer

[image: Annoying navigation bar]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called Breadcrumb.
You just have to click on it's icon which is here :

[image: Button highlighted]